# Python: Connect via LAN?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Just a preface to this question: I have no clue what I am doing, so please excuse any stupidity.

I am making a socket based chatroom that I want to use on a local network (My dad's computer and mine connected through the same wifi).

Here is the server code:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
while True:
    # Find connections
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        data = connection.recv(999)
        print data

    except:
        connection.close()
```

Here is the client:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address

while True:
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect(server_address)
        message=raw_input('Message: ')
        if message=='quit':
            break
        sock.sendall(message)
    except:
        break
sock.close()
```

When I run the client on one computer, and the server on the other.. the connection isn't made. I believe it is because of `server_address = ('localhost', 10000)` but I am not sure.. any suggestions?

Comment: How do I find that? `ipconfig`? And where do a put each?

Comment: ipconfig or ifconfig in linux, and you have tu put your ip in the server code ¨server_address = ('myip', 10000)¨ and you have to put a client in the computer of your dad and in the client you have to put this ¨server_address = ('myip', 10000)¨

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Add that as an answer.

Comment: @aIKid Sure, wait a minute :)

Comment: Worked perfect! Just can't figure out how to make the server send all messages back to the client.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use your local ip's for example if you are going to be the server you have to use your own ip in the server code:

to find the ip:

```
ipconfig - Windows CMD
ifconfig - Linux Shell, Mac Terminal
```

after you know your ip you have to replace `localhost` with your own ip:

Server code:

```
server_address = ('myip', 10000)
```

so in your father's computer you have to connect to your server:

Client Code:

```
server_address = ('myip', 10000)
```