# Can't access localhost site from other device

Tags: python, sockets, localhost

I've wrote a simple program that binds to the machine internal ip and to port 80, the http port.

```
import socket
import time as t
from datetime import datetime


def gettime():
    unix_stamp = t.time()
    dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_stamp)
    dt_object = str(dt_object).split()
    return dt_object[1], dt_object[0]


HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print(f"[LOG::{gettime()[0]}]   {HOST}")
PORT = 80

index = open("index.html", "r")

MySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
MySocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
MySocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
MySocket.listen(3)


client_socket, (client_ip, client_port) = MySocket.accept()
print(f"[LOG::{gettime()[0]}]   {client_ip}:{client_port}")
client_socket.send(index.read().encode('utf-8'))

client_socket.shutdown(1)

t.sleep(10)

client_socket.close()
print(f'[LOG::{gettime()[0]}]    DONE AND CLOSED')
```

When I try connecting to my site from the machine on which the script is run, I get the website and everything. But when I try from my phone or another machine, it can't connect to the site.
My 'server-side' laptop has a wired connection. Both the phone and the other machine are wirelessly connected to the modem-router or and access point to that modem-router.

Comment: How are you accessing the site fom your phone? Are you just doing `http://localhost:80`?

Comment: no , a line in my program prints the ip of my host machine. and i try to connect via: `http://ip:80`

Comment: Does this IP happen to be `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: no it's 192.168.99.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work on a local network, the HOST value must be different to your external local address, example 192.168.1.10. If in this case you do not have a connection, then the problem may be in the network settings of the OS or router.

Comment: So the HOST variable must be something else than my own internet ip?

Comment: It depends on the network you work on. [Detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20696006/13693135)

Comment: Ok ,i've taken a closer look to the `ìpconfig ` command. I'ven oticed it uses the ip address from one of my virtualbox ethernet adaptors. I've changed my script so i can manually give in the correct ip address. Is there any way i can still get the ip from the correct adaptor? p.s. If you update your answer i'll accept it.